# CSS white-space nowrap doesn't seem to be working, possibly different issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, range

I'm trying to append a plus sign to my range slider. It appears below the slider rather than after the number. I'm sure this is a simple fix, but I can't figure out what I've done wrong here.

Here is a jsfiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/61cm5vmm/

```
<style>
.sliderGroup {
    float: left;
    width:250px;
    height:50px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    background-color: rgb(230,255,230)
} 

.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.daysAR {
    height: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
    </style>
<div class="center">
<div class="sliderGroup">
<div class="daysAR">
<label for="days">Days in Accounts Recievable</label><br />
<input type="range" min="0" max="61" value="30" id="days" step="1" oninput="accountsRecievableSlider(value);average1();average4()">
<output for="days" id="daysInAR">30</output><p id="plus"></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your `p` tag to `span`.

**Code to be changed:** `<span id="plus"></span>`

Check out below:

```js
 function accountsRecievableSlider(AR) {
  document.querySelector('#daysInAR').value = AR;
  var selectday = document.querySelector('#daysInAR').value
  if (selectday > 60){
    document.getElementById("plus").innerHTML =("+")
  } else{
    document.getElementById("plus").innerHTML =("")
   }
 }
```

```css
.sliderGroup {
    float: left;
 width:250px;
 height:50px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 3px solid black;
 background-color: rgb(230,255,230)
} 

.center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
}

.daysAR {
 height: 50px;
 white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<div class="sliderGroup">
<div class="daysAR">
<label for="days">Days in Accounts Recievable</label><br />
<input type="range" min="0" max="61" value="30" id="days" step="1" oninput="accountsRecievableSlider(value);average1();average4()">
<output for="days" id="daysInAR">30</output><span id="plus"></span>
</div 
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using a block level element, like `<p>`. Simply changing it to something that is naturally inline like `<span>` fixes this issue. [Learn about the box model!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mojkvp0/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the plus from paragraph to span and it works as you need it.

```
<span id="plus"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

P is a block element, block elements dont allow any other elements to settle in same line with them , use span a inline element which settles beside any other element in same line for more information about block and inline elements please 
visit the link below

http://www.impressivewebs.com/difference-block-inline-css/

```css
.sliderGroup {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: rgb(230, 255, 230)
}
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
}
.daysAR {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <div class="sliderGroup">
    <div class="daysAR">
      <label for="days">Days in Accounts Recievable</label>
      <br />
      <input type="range" min="0" max="61" value="30" id="days" step="1" oninput="accountsRecievableSlider(value);average1();average4()">
      <output for="days" id="daysInAR">30</output><span id="plus">+</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```